# Remove H1 title in admin post edit screen

Tags: plugins, php, custom-post-types, plugin-development, hooks

As a priority i need to just display some custom html inside the Title(h1.wp-heading-inline) in the Post Edit Screen (Top Left Corner). While trying various methods i found that all html is filtered only text is displayed.

If there is no way to prevent the filtering of html of H1 title in admin page then i would like to remove it for Custom Post Type's posts.

Here is what i tried:

```
add_action( 'edit_form_top', [$this, 'customPostTitle' ] );
```

```
function customPostTitle($title) {
        global $post;
        if ($post->post_type == $this::POST_TYPE['id']) {
            $custom_post_title = $post->post_title;
            $custom_title_fin = __( 'Custom post title: ', 'custom-plugin' ) . '<span class="custom-class">'. $custom_post_title . '</a>';
            $title = $custom_title_fin;
        }

        return $title;
    }
```

Is there any actions/filters i can do to achieve this ?

I don't want to use js/css - i am looking for a native/php way ?

Comment: FYI the `edit_form_top` hook is an action, not a filter, so `return` does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing "Add New Post" to a string with unescaped HTML tags cannot be accomplished using only PHP: [WordPress core escapes](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/edit.php#L410-L414) any HTML in the CPT's label for that text.

Additionally (again, only using PHP), there is no way to remove that block of text: setting the `add_new_item` label to blank when registering the CPT results in "Add New" being displayed.

Your best option is to use CSS to hide the core text, and then add your own `<h1>`:

```php
add_action( 'edit_form_top', static function () {
    if ( empty( $_GET['post'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $post_id = absint( $_GET['post'] );

    if ( 'wpse416980' !== get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<style>.wrap h1.wp-heading-inline { display: none; }</style>';

    printf( 
        '<h1>%s<span class="custom-class">%s</span></h1>',
        __( 'Custom post title: ', 'custom-plugin' ),
        get_the_title( $post_id )
    );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks. Shame there is no hook for post admin title...